# How to install RVM on Linux subsystem on Windows 10

Tags: ruby, windows-10, ubuntu-14.04, rvm, apt-get

I am working on a web-scraping script, but the current gem version is not giving me the any packages to install.

I know it's for some infrastructure-change reason but now I have installed anniversary-update from Windows 10 and installed a Linux subsystem.

I installed NodeJS + npm already, which are working correctly but the problem is installing Ruby on that subsystem.

When I tried to install   RVM  it's giving me an error:

```
ins@DESKTOP-TK9ELEL:~$ sudo apt-get install rvm 
sudo: unable to resolve host DESKTOP-TK9ELEL
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:

 rvm : Depends: libreadline6-dev but it is not installable
       Depends: autoconf but it is not installable
       Depends: libgdbm-dev but it is not installable
       Depends: libncurses5-dev but it is not installable
       Depends: automake but it is not installable
       Depends: libtool but it is not installable
       Depends: bison but it is not installable
       Depends: pkg-config but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

How do I solve this?

Answer (score 3):

Follow the [install directions for RVM](https://rvm.io/rvm/install) on their site. Nobody knows RVM better than the authors.

```
\curl -sSL https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable --ruby
```

That will install the stable versions of RVM and Ruby.

Following that use:

```
rvm use [whichever Ruby was installed] --default
```

to tell RVM to default to that Ruby.

RVM is capable of installing the prerequisites for your *nix distribution if you use their directions. Once RVM is installed you will not need to use `sudo` or `yum` to install anything for an RVM-managed Ruby. That means *do not* use `sudo rvm install ruby...` or `sudo gem install some_gem`. If you do you'll only force your system to do the wrong thing.

Comment: ya i have tried this before but got error >>> GPG signature verification failed for '/home/ins/.rvm/archives/rvm-1.27.0.tgz' - 'https://github.com/rvm/rvm/releases/download/1.27.0/1.27.0.tar.gz.asc'!

Comment: Did you do the first step in the install directions? If so, did you search for any support questions about that?

Comment: for anyone finding this way later, you need to setup gpg keys before you can use the curl install as stated in the directions link `gpg --keyserver hkp://pool.sks-keyservers.net --recv-keys 409B6B1796C275462A1703113804BB82D39DC0E3 7D2BAF1CF37B13E2069D6956105BD0E739499BDB`